# Installation failed since the device has an application with the same package but a different signature

Tags: android, jar-signing

I have uploaded app by signed application using V1 and V2. After that I download the application from google play and run same version from Android Studio it show me dialog of "Installation failed since the device has an application with the same package but a different signature. . . .."

Can you suggest me what I am doing wrong need to update the build.gradle for V1?

Because I am running release variant with signed configurations.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you cannot have two apps with same package name in a device.

Comment: If we install same application with same package name and same signed configurations we will never get the dialog like this